# Pull a pre-determined number of results from a react-query cache

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Basically just this. I may be missing it but was wondering if there is a built in way to pull say the first three results from a cached query for instance I can query a list of blog posts in one query and in another component display the newest three but still have the full cache available when I need it.

I know I could loop through the to the set number but would rather use built in functionality if available.

Thanks in advance

I have googled it but can't seem to find what I'm looking for one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

`useQuery` is usually all you need, and it can pull specific things from the cache with the `select` option.

The key thing to understand is that `useQuery` will read from the cache only as long as data in the cache is considered fresh, which can be customized by setting a `staleTime`:

```
const usePosts = (select) => useQuery({
  queryKey: [posts],
  queryFn: () => fetchPosts(),
  select
})

const useTopThreePosts = usePosts(posts => posts.slice(0,3))
```